FastAPI VSCode debug in new alpine docker container
I had to update the base image for my python backend from the now deprecated FastAPI image to a newer Alpine version. Dockerfile below...
However, now I can not get VSCode debugger back up because:
cd /fastapi ; /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../deb
ugpy/launcher 53213 -- -m uvicorn main:app --reload --port 8001 
/usr/bin/python3: No module named uvicorn

launch.json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: FastAPI",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "args": [
                "main:app",
                "--reload",
                "--port",
                "8001"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.10-alpine3.20

COPY ./fastapi/app /app
COPY ./fastapi/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./fastapi/start-reload.sh /start-reload.sh
COPY ./docker/memcached.sh /memcached.sh

USER root

ENV HOSTNAME fastapi
ENV PYTHONPATH '/:/app'
ENV IS_PROD 1
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin

RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-connector-c-dev memcached &&\
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        build-base \
        mariadb-dev &&\
    apk add php83 &&\
    apk add gcc musl-dev &&\
    apk del .build-deps

RUN apk add py3-pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    echo 'asdf'

# CLEANUP

RUN apk cache clean &&\
    apk del gcc musl-dev

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

requirements.txt
fastapi[standard]
debugpy
pydantic
pytz
requests
python-dateutil
numpy
scipy
pymemcache
mysqlclient

I also tried to attach to a running endpoint using debugpy attach but could not get that to work either...
I dont understand why the module is missing because it is installed
/fastapi # pip list | grep uvicorn
uvicorn            0.30.6

------ EDIT ------
Answering comments
Here is the PYTHONPATH. Looks looks bit messed up, even when I remove the ENV command to modify it
/fastapi # env | grep PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/fastapi:/

Below is the Dockerfile CMD that actually does start up the server.
CMD ["python3", "-m", "debugpy", "--listen", "0.0.0.0:5678", "-m", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

buiosandbox    | 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
sandbox    | INFO:     Started server process [27]
sandbox    | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
sandbox    | INFO:     Application startup complete.


is you container running ?? if yes can you show the output of echo $PYTHONPATH inside the contaner

What does ENV PYTHONPATH '/:/app' stands for? Probably your redefined pythonpath doesn't find library installed with pip. I had no problems with following dockerfile: FROM python:3.11-alpine; COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt; RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt  (Difference with yours - I have no PYTHONPATH and no apk add py3-pip). Also, you can try moving your uvicorn to main.py (uvicorn.run(...)) and run like python main.py

It was the pythonpath setting, I was setting it with the ENV command and then again in the docker-compose file that starts the sandbox. Thanks for the pointers!
